# StackExchange.Redis Connect to multiple db

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using stackexchange redis client, I want to connect to multiple db not only one How can I handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md

You have to pass the DB number in the getDatabase() Method

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.connect("local host");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase(databaseNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in .Net Core, I have created a wrapper class which you can use like this:

```
var redisConnectionString = "{Your Redis Cache Connection String}";
var rest = new Restme(redisConnectionString);

//get cache data (support Generic cast)
var cacheResult = rest.Get("home:testKey");
var cacheResult2 = rest.Get<bool>("home:testKey2");
var cacheResult3 = rest.Get<ObjectType>("home:testKey3");

//set cache data
rest.Post("home:testKey","value");
rest.Post<bool>("home:testKey2",true);
```

it's actually a simple wrapper of StackExchange.Redis, so if you want to conect to multiple databases, just simply instantiate multiple Restme() objects as separate variables, each contains different Redis db connection.

The source code is in github: https://github.com/oelite/RESTme